# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/[Path to project]' on mac

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, django-silk

I am trying to set up [django-silk](https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk) in my django project and I keep running into this issue when I run `python manage.py collectstatic`. I have tried creating a new virtual environment and trying again but I get the same error. But if I were to create a new django project with only Dango Rest Framework and Silk everything works fine. I have been stuck on this issue for several days. Can anyone help?

My environment: 
MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
python 3.7.3
Django 2.2.10
djangorestframework 3.9.1
django-silk 3.0.4
Project location: /Users/cstephenson/Desktop/repos/MyProject

Full stack trace:

```
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 352, in copy_file
    self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 52, in save
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 242, in _save
    os.makedirs(directory)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 211, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "/Users/cstephenson/Desktop/myenv/bin/../lib/python3.7/os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/[Path to project]'
```

Comment: Where is the project (i.e. what is the actual `/[Path to project]`), and which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Up dated my original question with all the data you requested.

Comment: Does it actually literally say `'/[Path to project]'` in the error message? If so, I'm pretty sure there's a placeholder somewhere (maybe a config file) that has this, but needs to be replaced with the actual path. (And that error makes sense, because under macOS Catalina the root filesystem is read-only, so creating a new top-level folder named "`[Path to project]`" there *should* get you a read-only file system error.)

Comment: Yea, it literally does say [Path to project]

Comment: You could search for that string with something like `grep -Fr '[Path to project]' /Users/cstephenson/Desktop/repos` to get an idea where the problem might be. (Note: the `-F` option to `grep` is needed so it doesn't interpret this as a bracket expression, and search for *any of* the letters between `[` and `]`.)

Comment: @ChristopherStephenson, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @avriis I did by creating a fresh project and copying over the static files.